# Is there any point in using DI for class injections

Tags: angular

In angular1 we often used factory to inject classes, not instances. In angular2, I can do the same:

```
{provide: MyClass, useFactory: () => { return MyClass }}

...
constructor(MyClass) {
   let instance = new MyClass();
}
```

However, I remember reading that this was justified by the absence of JS modules. Now that we use ES6 modules, I'm wondering if there is any need to use DI for class injections? I see many libraries that don't use angular DI to get classes, but access them through `import` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{provide: MyClass, useFactory: () => { return MyClass }}
```

and

```
{provide: MyClass, useValue: MyClass }
```

are essentially the same thing. Yes, it makes sense to use DI for the classes that are supposed to be instantiated manually.

It creates no problems when DI is performed in JS (ES.Next):

```
constructor(@Inject(MyClass) MyClass) {
  this.MyClass = new MyClass;
}
```

But it may be less convenient to use in TypeScript because the types should be properly specified:

```
constructor(@Inject(MyClass) MyClass: typeof MyClass) {
  this.MyClass = new MyClass;
}
```

Having it as a provider allows to replace or augment the functionality any time without patching the original code, which is a good trait for third-party libraries.

And it offers better testability, `MyClass` can be replaced with a stub class or spy function. When no DI is involved, this makes testing more complicated and requires to implement DI on import level, e.g. with `rewire-webpack`.

Comment: `{provide: MyClass, useValue: MyClass }` should be `{provide: MyClass, useClass: MyClass }` or just `MyClass`, probably `{provide: MyClass, useFactory: () => { return MyClass }}` was also meant to be `{provide: MyClass, useFactory: () => { return new MyClass() }}`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, nope, his example is correct, he wants to provide a class, not an instance

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Should it? In the case of useValue a class is injected. In the case of useClass a class instance is injected.

Comment: You are right, I didn't fully read the question. I don't know Angular1 and it didn't really make sense to me. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Sure, no problems.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use TypeScript import statements to make a type known within a `*.ts` file. This is entirely different than DI and not really related to DI, except that such imported types can be used as DI provider key to request dependencies.

You can just create class instances with `new MyClass()`.

If your class has dependencies like `Http` from Angulars `HttpModule` like

```
class MyClass {
  constructor(this.http:Http) {}
}
```

using DI is convenient because you get the `MyClass` instance created by DI and also the `Http` parameter passed in automatically.

DI (Inversion of Control) is also a common programming pattern which makes testing easier, because your resulting classes are not tightly coupled.

DI is hiearchical and makes it easy to share instances with specific scopes (for example a component instance and all it's children)

Comment: thanks, _This is entirely different than DI and not really related to DI_ - well, in anglular1, this was a common pattern to inject classes with DI. So as I understand from your answer, if a class has no dependencies, there is no point in using DI, correct?

Comment: It's also the other way around. If other classes depend on your class, DI is also useful. If you want to share an instance with different components, directives, pipes, or other services, then DI is quite convenient because DI takes care that a specific instance gets injected. Injected classes replace `$scope` from Angular1. See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service and https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dependency-injection.html

Comment: yeah, thanks. not sure that I expressed my question clearly though, because you're talking about instances, I'm taking about classes. _Injected classes replace $scope from Angular1_ - we used that pattern in angular1 as well :)

Comment: "Instance" is quite important in DI context. Depending on where you register a DI provider, you might get the same instance injected in different places (singleton), or different instances.

Comment: yeah, sure, because DI is hierarchic. right, `instance` makes sense in the DI context and I have no second thoughts about it