# Point of using Services for simple utility functions in angular

Tags: angular

I have a question about services in angular.

Let's say I have this simple service:

```
 @Injectable()
 export class ApplicationUtilsService {

 constructor() {
}

 checkIfObjectExistAndGet(map: Map<string, Object>, sectionName: string): Object {
     return map.has(sectionName) ? map.get(sectionName) : {};
   }

}
```

Why not just create and export a function:

```
export function  checkIfObjectExistAndGet(map: Map<string, Object>, sectionName: string): Object {
 return map.has(sectionName) ? map.get(sectionName) : {};
```

}

That way I can import it whenever I want to use it. Don't need to inject it into component so tests are little easier to create (I dont need to provide service or create mock).

So I'm wondering if those type of functions should be provided by services or is it ok to just create it as in example above and import?

Comment: [I wondered that once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42350057/is-there-any-point-in-using-di-for-class-injections) myself and still have no definite opinion

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely no problem with that In this simple use case! However, imagine when your application grows and there is a need to reference a map or some other object serving as a resource store across perhaps adjacent (not nested) subtrees of your component hierarchy... How do you accomplish this such that you don't make unnecessary API requests or replay expensive operations? Encapsulate you're map/resource/object in a service such that now it's a singleton (it only will create itself once) and now you have efficiency and flexibility